# Problems using genfromtxt to input into scikit-learn fit function

Tags: csv, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to genfromtxt to read in a csv file and then use RandomForestClassifier. I wind up having use genfromtxt twice;once to read in the features and then to get the proper format.
The code for this attempt follows:
   import csv 
    import numpy as np

```
data = np.genfromtxt('plants.csv',dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)
feature_names = np.array(data.dtype.names)
feature_names = feature_names[[ 0,1,2,3,4]] 

data = np.genfromtxt('plants.csv',dtype=float, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
plants_X = data[:, [0,1,2,3,4]] 
_y = np.ravel(data[:,[5]]) #Return a flattened array required by scikit-learn fit for 2nd argument

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
clf = RandomForestClassifier( n_estimators = 10, random_state = 33)
clf = clf.fit(plants_X, plants_y)

print feature_names, '\n', clf.feature_importances_

print feature_names, '\n', clf.feature_importances_
```

When I use genfromtxt with the "names=True option  "data" read in is not in the format I expected!

" ([(31.194181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
       (12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), (18.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
       (31.194181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)], 
       ...
      dtype=[('A', '

I want to get the feature names from the file without reading it twice!

Thanks for your assistance!

Ps: Thnaks to "Cyborg" I got this far!

Answer (score 2):

I recomment to use pandas for this.
You can use `pandas.read_csv` to get a pandas dataframe with column names. You need to convert the data to a numpy array to pass it to scikit-learn, though.

Comment: I'd like to see if there is a way to use a single genfromtxt method whose output could be coerced into the proper format if possible. Thoughts Andreas, others?

Comment: You can read a single line from the file, extract and then call genfromtext on the remaining descriptor I guess. Why do you not want to use the function that is made exactly for your purpose?

Comment: Hi Andreas, because I am not sure how to use it ... may I impose for an example in code? thnaks, Chris